# max and min of $f(x,y)=\sqrt{xy(x-y^2+3)}$ on its domain

Tags: real-analysis

To study max and min of this function can I study max and min of $g(x,y)=xy(x-y^2+3)$ because the square root is a crescent strictly function?

Comment: Yes, with the restriction $xy(x-y^3 + 3) \geq 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no. The problem is that your function $g$ doesn't have a min. (Pick $x = 1$ and let $y$ increase to $\infty$; then $g$ approaches $-\infty$.

The key thing about $f$, where the square root is included, is that it is **only defined** at places where $g(x, y) \ge 0$. That's what the "on its domain" part of the problem means.

So what you *can* do is this:

1. Find the domain of $f$, i.e., find the region on which $g$ is nonnegative.
2. On that region, find the locations of the max and min of $g$.
3. Compute $f$ at those locations. (The problem says to find the max and min of 
   $f$, not the locations of the max and min.)

Comment: Is the gradient null in $(0,0),(-3,0),(0,\sqrt{3}),(0,-\sqrt{3}),(-{6 \over 5},-\sqrt{3 \over 5})$ ?

Comment: In $(-{6 \over 5},-{\sqrt{3 \over 5}}$ there is a local max, not global because if I consider $f(x,1)\rightarrow +\infty$ for $x \rightarrow +\infty$. The global min is where f is null?

Comment: I have no idea about the answers to these questions, as I have not done the calculus/algebra work. I just answered the question you asked, which was a good one.

Answer (score 0):

The domain gives $xy(x-y^2+3)\geq0$ and we see that
$$\min_{xy(x-y^2+3)\geq0}f(x,y)=f(0,0)=0.$$

Now, let $x=-1$ and $y\rightarrow+\infty.$

Thus, $f(x,y)\rightarrow+\infty,$ which says that the maximum  does not exist.